# Gdb inside container gets terminated with 137

Tags: c++, kubernetes, gdb, sigterm

When I run gdb on my binary inside kubernetes pod in  container it starts loading  symbol after that it  suddenly gets terminated with SIGTERM and exit code 137. I checked for describe pod it shows reason Error. I have added ptrace capabilities in yaml. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Exit code 137 means that the process was killed by signal 9 (137=128+9). Most likely reason is that container was running out of memory and gdb was killed by OOM Killer. Check `dmesg` output for any messages from OOM Killer.

Comment: I checked, it shows reason : Error no OOMKilled field is there. It just shows 137, program received sigterm I think since gdb tries to stop primary process kubernetes might send some signal to stop it. I not sure though.